# Microsoft Teams Switching To Wrong Account

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams keeps switching me to the wrong account. I created a free Teams account using my G Suite work email address. To set it up, it sent a code to my personal Gmail account, which is also the address for my paid Microsoft Office account. When I log in using the G Suite address, there's a message saying "We're switching you to your other account." It then logs in to my personal Gmail account. I don’t see an option to shift to the G Suite account. I’ve logged out and back in dozens of times. Same result. I tried changing the password of the G Suite account but instead it changed the password of the Gmail account. Does anybody know now I can log into the G Suite account?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using incognito browsers for multiple sessions. I personally use the desktop application for one account and the browser for the other account.

The issue is around cookies being cached on the domain. Clearing the cache should solve the problem if you don't want to try any of my previous suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I tried incognito mode and it almost worked but it required allowing third party cookies. As soon as a I did it took me it logged me back in to the personal account again instead of the work account. I really only need to use the work account. Do you know how to get the desktop app to accept that?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. i do use desk top for a work account and didnt have to do anything in particular

Comment: FYI, I also tried clearing the cache. Same result. I still can't log into the G Suite account. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I upvoted this answer. I routinely experience this. I use one account "_in the clear_" and the other account "_incognito_." If things "_get wonky_", I close things down, clear the browser cache, and start over. That [almost?] always works.